# Test whether a method returns doubles

Tags: java

Here is a paraphrasing of a question I posed to a group of students, and it turns out that finding an answer is a bit trickier (for me, anyway) than I expected:

*Suppose you have asked me to write a method, f, that has a String parameter, and returns a double.  You now wish to test whether I have done my job correctly by writing your own test code that will compile if I have written f as specified, but won't compile if I have not.*

Some students proposed this incorrect solution:

```
System.out.println(f("cat"));
```

This is not a good tester because it does not test the return type of the method.  That is, it will compile even if I had written f to return a String or an int or a boolean, and so on.

I proposed this solution to the students:

```
double d = f("cat");
```

I reasoned that this tests whether f accepts Strings and returns doubles.  But really, this is no good either.  f could return an int (or any "narrower" primitive data type), and the result could be stored in d.

So, I'm seeking ideas for a *simple* solution (one or two lines of code, perhaps?) to the problem: *write code that will compile if f has been defined correctly (String parameter, double return), but won't compile if f has not been written as specified.*

Comment: [Reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/).

Comment: I realize that Java's Reflection exists, but have not used it.  I don't know that it satisfies the "test at compile time" part of the posed problem, but I do know that Reflection comes with a lot of overhead.  Is there a non-Reflection solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reflection is the best fit here in general (it's a pretty unusual requirement) but something else that would at least work would be to use overload resolution: provide alternative methods with a parameter of `float`, `long` and `Double`, but with `void` return types... and one with a method with a parameter of type `double` and a non-void return type. Then check that you can assign a value to the result of calling that method with the result of `f`. For example:

```
public void foo(long x) {}
public void foo(float x) {}
public void foo(Double x) {}
public void foo(Object x) {}
public int foo(double x) {
    return 0;
}

// This will only compile if f is declared to return double
int check = foo(f("cat"));
```

Comment: Shouldn't `check` be `double`? (Although it doesn't really matter for the compiler)

Comment: @MarounMaroun: Nope - it's the same return type as the type returned by `foo`, which is entirely distinct from the type returned by `f`. The important thing is that it's a non-void method... that's all we really care about.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a compile-time assertion (although it will yield *false-positive* for `Double` and `Object`):

```
List<Double> a = new ArrayList<Double>();
a.add(f("cat"));
```

Or simply:

```
double[] a = {f("cat")};
```

And here is a runtime assertion (although it will yield *false-positive* for `Double`, `Float` and `float`):

```
try
{
    double d = f("cat")/0;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    return false;
}
return true;
```

Comment: For your first solution, I like it, and it suggests that the ArrayList is unnecessary...just try to store the return in a Double.  But what if f had been mis-written to return a Double rather than a double?

Comment: @normKrumpe, as I said: "it will yield *false-positive* for `Double`".

Answer (score 0):

Use reflection: obtain the instance of the class java.lang.reflect.method that matches with the name f and parameter type String, of that instance use the return type is equal to Double.TYPE

from the class docs of the class Double:

public static final Class TYPE The Class instance representing the primitive type double

Answer (score 0):

We can return Object types rather than and disable autoboxing in the compiler options of IDE to error to get the exact return type as well.ex: int cannot return Integer..etc

For primitives, we need reflection which might be a bit heavy operation.